# How to get properties from dynamic view of COM Object which are shown in dynamic view while debugging

Tags: dynamic, view

I am trying to read an excel workbook and named ranged it has. I need to get name and value of each named range workbook has. When I debug I can see the property in dynamic view, but can't figure out how to get in the code. Here is my code which reads from excel

```
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook excelWb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
            Excel._Worksheet excelWs = excelWb.Worksheets[1];
            Excel.Range excelRange = excelWs.UsedRange;
            Excel.Names namedRanges = excelWb.Names;
            
            foreach (var nameRange in namedRanges)
            {
                //foreach (var prop in nameRange.GetType().GetProperties())
                //{
                //    string propName = prop.Name;
                //    object value = prop.GetValue(nameRange, null);
                //}
                var n = (dynamic)nameRange.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties();
                var m = (dynamic)nameRange.GetType().GetProperties();
            }
```

I need to get name and value of named range, which I can see in dynamic view while debugging.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZu5j.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get by minor change in the code

```
        foreach (Name nameRange in namedRanges)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{nameRange.Name}: {nameRange.Value}");
        }
```